# using boost signals instead of qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt4

This is a long shot but, having come across a constrain in a form of a qt's signals, slots being unable to be templatized, I'm just thinking of replacing them with boost signals, would that be viable option?

Comment: How would we know? In general yes, there's absolutely nothing wrong with Boost.Signals, but it's up to you to decide if Boost is right for your particular problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not forced to use qt's signals and slots. From [Using Qt with 3rd Party Signals and Slots](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#id-4d7e6cf0-92b1-4743-8729-5cd701b68cad):

> It is possible to use Qt with a 3rd party signal/slot mechanism. You
>   can even use both mechanisms in the same project. Just add the
>   following line to your qmake project (.pro) file.
>
> ```
> CONFIG += no_keywords
> ```
>
> It tells Qt not to define the moc keywords signals, slots, and emit,
>   because these names will be used by a 3rd party library, e.g. Boost.
>   Then to continue using Qt signals and slots with the no_keywords flag,
>   simply replace all uses of the Qt moc keywords in your sources with
>   the corresponding Qt macros Q_SIGNALS (or Q_SIGNAL), Q_SLOTS (or
>   Q_SLOT), and Q_EMIT.

There is a [complete explanation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/signals/s04.html#id3080999) of how to connect boost signals to qt signals.

---

I found this adapter somewhere on the net, but no idea where:

```
#ifndef _QT_2_FUNC_3_H_
#define _QT_2_FUNC_3_H_

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

#include <QObject>

#include <libQtSignalAdapters/QtConnDefault.h>

using namespace boost;

namespace QtSignalAdapters
{

/**
* \cond
*/
template<typename SIGNATURE>
class Qt2FuncSlot3
{
public:
    typedef function<SIGNATURE> FuncType;
    typedef typename function_traits<SIGNATURE>::arg1_type ParmType1;
    typedef typename function_traits<SIGNATURE>::arg2_type ParmType2;
    typedef typename function_traits<SIGNATURE>::arg3_type ParmType3;

    Qt2FuncSlot3(const FuncType& func) :
        func_(func)
    {
    }

    void call(QObject* sender, void **arguments)
    {
        ParmType1* a1 = reinterpret_cast<ParmType1*>(arguments[1]);
        ParmType2* a2 = reinterpret_cast<ParmType2*>(arguments[2]);
        ParmType3* a3 = reinterpret_cast<ParmType3*>(arguments[3]);
        if ( func_ )
            func_(*a1,*a2, *a3);
    }

private:
    FuncType func_;
};
/**
* \endcond
*/

template<typename SIGNATURE>
class Qt2Func3 : public QObject, public QtConnDefault
{
public:
    typedef function<SIGNATURE> FuncType;
    typedef typename function_traits<SIGNATURE>::arg1_type ParmType;

    Qt2Func3(QObject* qobject, int signalIdx, const FuncType& func,
            bool initiallyConnected=true) :
        QObject(qobject),
        QtConnDefault(qobject, signalIdx),
        func_(func)
    {
        //
        // Get the next usable slot ID on this...
        //
        slotIdx_ = metaObject()->methodCount();

        //
        // Create a slot to handle invoking the boost::function object.
        //
        slot_ = new Qt2FuncSlot3<SIGNATURE>(func);

        if ( initiallyConnected )
            connect();
    }

    ~Qt2Func3()
    {
        delete slot_;
    }

    int qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call c, int id, void **arguments)
    {
        id = QObject::qt_metacall(c, id, arguments);
        if ( id < 0 || c != QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod )
            return id;

        slot_->call(sender(), arguments);
        return -1;
    }

    void connect()
    {
        connect_();
    }

    void disconnect()
    {
        disconnect_();
    }

private:
    void connect_()
    {
        connected_ =
            QMetaObject::connect(qobject_, signalIdx_, this, slotIdx_);
    }

    void disconnect_()
    {
        connected_ =
            !QMetaObject::disconnect(qobject_, signalIdx_, this, slotIdx_);
    }


    FuncType func_;
    Qt2FuncSlot3<SIGNATURE>* slot_;
};

}

#endif
```

So, basically you have to reimplement `qt_metacall` function.

Comment: Qt 5 supports connecting signals to arbitrary functions out of the box - see http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax  For Qt 4, there are a few adapter libraries.  My attempt at this plus links to others can be found at https://github.com/robertknight/qt-signal-tools

Comment: @RobertKnight Should have been an answer (a good one, if you ask me). btw finaly they made a good decision regarding their signal/slots