# Using any c++ function as a Qt slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qwidget

Is there a way to use any C++ function as a Qt slot, without having its class inheriting from QWidget?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a duplicated, but this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533906/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You cannot in Qt versions < Qt 5.**

In order to use signals/slots the meta object compiler has to be invoked. To make this happen your class should meet the following requirements:

- Inherit from `QObject` or any other subclass (eg `QWidget`, `QPushButton` etc)
- The `Q_OBJECT` macro should be defined in the private section of the class in order to enable meta-object features such as slots
- Use the `Qt` keywords `slots` and `signals` in order to declare which functions should be handles by the meta compiler as slots or signals

For more details check the corresponding documentation pages about the [meta-object system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html#meta-object-system) and the [signals & slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

Also check the [`QObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QObject.html) documentation:

> **Notice that the `Q_OBJECT` macro is mandatory for any object that implements signals, slots or properties.** You also need to run the
>   Meta Object Compiler on the source file. We strongly recommend the use
>   of this macro in all subclasses of QObject regardless of whether or
>   not they actually use signals, slots and properties, since failure to
>   do so may lead certain functions to exhibit strange behavior.

**Edit: Since Qt 5, functors and lambda expressions can be used as slot. See [`New Signal Slot Syntax in Qt 5`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QObject.html)**

Comment: Importantly, however, while this is not possible in Qt 4, it IS going to be possible in Qt 5, using the new signal/slot mechanism. http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: You are right, but IMHO it should be used only in rare cases. Using slots is more elegant than using tr1::bind with simple functions.

Comment: i absolutely agree, they should be a rare occurance. A lot like short cirquit if statements, they are useful in a very narrow set of circumstances, and in those cases increase readability and ease of maintenance. But, they should only be used then, not as a general rule.

Answer (score 8):

Since Qt 5, functors and lambda expressions can be used as slot (as previously mentioned, here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

As I could not find example code, I added the following:

This example uses `boost::function` for a class member `ClassName::classMember()` without parameters.

```
    boost::function<void()> f= boost::bind(&ClassName::classMember, classInstance);
    connect(QObjectInstance, &QObject::signalName, f);
```

When the Qt signal and class member have parameters (for instance `ClassName::classMember(int)`), the boost function should be adapted as follows:

```
    boost::function<void(int)> f= boost::bind(&ClassName::classMember, classInstance, _1);
```

More information on boost::bind can be found in the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html

Answer (score 4):

In Qt 5, you can.  See http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

In Qt 4, this is not directly supported but there are a couple of libraries which provide this functionality by proxying the signal via a slot in a hidden QObject which then calls your non-slot function.  My attempt at this can be found at https://github.com/robertknight/qt-signal-tools .  There are links to other implementations on the bottom of the README.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. The Qt-meta-object-compiler (**moc**) wraps the function, are marked as **slot**-s, in relatively large code-wrapper. Files, created by **moc**, begin with **moc_**, look them.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to inherit QObject: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html